# Can dynamic views modify array rows on the basis of which they have been created?

Tags: swiftui

I've been trying to wrap my head about some key concepts of SwiftUI. There is one thing I still don't really understand.

The situation:

1. Have an array of structs that contain various values.
2. Dynamically create views (e.g. Circles) by iterating through this array with ForEach.
3. Question: Are the newly created views somehow connected to their corresponding array rows? If something changes about a Circle, can this Circle save that change back to the Struct in the Array from which it was created?

I made a chart to illustrate this:

[image]

The use case/issue I'm referring to is: I create a number of Circles this way. The circles then animate, but I need to track their position... Can I make them update it back at the Array as they go?

Thank you!

EDIT: Example code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct blackCircle: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var position: CGPoint!
}

class CircleStorage: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var circles = [
        
        blackCircle(position: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)),
        blackCircle(position: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100)),
        blackCircle(position: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50))
        
    ]
    
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var circleStorage = CircleStorage()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
       
            ForEach(circleStorage.circles, id: \.id) {
                circle in
                
                Circle()
                    .position(circle.position)
                    .frame(width:44, height:44)
      
            }
  
        }
}
}
```

This creates three circles. I need to iterate through the circles, check their position and e.g. remove ones that have x over a certain value. I can do that by iterating through the Array - it contains positions where Circles are created. But what if their position changes at runtime by means of animation or dragging etc.? Can I make sure corresponding rows contain an up-to-date position even if it changes?

Comment: Can you post minimal reproducible code?

Comment: Once `circleStorage.circles` changes (for any reason or any place) the `ForEach` container will be updated and internal Circles redrawn. This is reactive nature of SwiftUI.

Comment: Agreed, so that would cover updating things from the container to ForEach to Circles. I meant however updating from the Circle to the container. If you grab the Circle at runtime and move it, or it animates itself to another position, the corresponding row still just contains the initial location. I'd like it to keep track of the current position even if the Circle is being moved around.

Comment: How do you think the drag works? In my eyes it would be an onDrag event that writes to the data which means the circles will move.

Comment: Good point, thanks! So I can update data each step of onDrag gesture so that both Circle and data are up to date on location. However, there's still the problem of Circles having timers and animations. Whereas I can save position to data on animation finished, I'm really not sure if it's possible to do it for each frame during the animation (what if the animation is looped?). Frankly speaking it was way easier in UIKit: just have an array of views and access their position anytime you please. In SwiftUI it seems not possible without meticulously manually logging each movement somewhere...